# Users Controller reset_password action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am planning on doing a reset_password functionality for my users.

Right now I am just working on the form. Right now I have one function reset_password. I want to make it so when a users does a POST to users/reset_password, it routes to the do_password_reset function.

Right now when they do a get, the form displays, but when they do a post I want to route it do a different action, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints

```
 match 'users/reset_password' => 'your_controller#reset_password', :via => :get

 match 'users/reset_password' => 'your_controller#do_password_reset', :via => :post
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that on the same page